# Azure to Auth0 connection - Invalid client secret is provided

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, auth0

I'm using Azure AD as my Identity Provider (IdP) and trying to connect Auth0 to it as a client. I've followed all the steps mentioned in
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2

Redirection from Auth0 to Azure AD is working as expected. Login on Azure AD side is also showing a success in its log, however I'm getting and error at Auth0 side which says,
"Invalid client secret is provided"
I've double checked the client secret. Freshly generated it to eliminate possiblity of its expiry but still gettting this error.
Below is an error message payload.

```
"error": {
      "message": "failed to obtain access token",
      "oauthError": "invalid_request",
      "type": "request-error",
      "payload": "{
          "error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.
            Trace ID: 52ea6301-3da2-46c7-b355-865dfff34c01
            Correlation ID: 69415f95-1430-45eb-b653-3c76f934ccc0
            Timestamp: 2021-11-29 05:11:57Z",
          "error_codes":[7000215],
          "timestamp":"2021-11-29 05:11:57Z",
          "trace_id":"52ea6301-3da2-46c7-b355-865dfff34c01",
          "correlation_id":"69415f95-1430-45eb-b653-3c76f934ccc0",
          "error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}"
    },
```

Comment: Make sure you have copied client secret value and not the client secret ID.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have copied client secret value and not the client secret ID.

Gave wrong value of client secret getting the same error as you.

[image]

Would Suggest you try with following parameter as I have set for authorization type OAuth2.0.

```
URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]
[image]

Given the correct value of Client Secret and getting the access token.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, check that the Azure AD Client secret is not expired. Otherwise, generate a new one, then update it in the enterprise connection configured with Auth0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33817322)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and tried all the possible solution mentioned in different URLs of stack overflow. But None of them worked for me. Below are the steps I tried and that worked for me.

Also, I have tried this using "OAuth" and "SAS"

1. Check the "App Registration"-> Click on {name of App} -> Click on "Certificates and Secrets"-> Click on "Client Secrets " ribbon.
2. If there are more than one client secrets , consider removing one which is not in use. Make sure to perform this task after checking the ids in the databrciks notebook mount code.
3. In Storage Account Check the "Access Control(IAM) then navigate to  "Storage Blob Contributor" and see the App registered is mentioned there or not. If the answer is no, trying adding it using "+" symbol and then click on "Add Registration"

If by any chance, none of the above worked for you, then do the below.

1. After Executing the ETL Job or any job in data bricks notebook, make sure to unmount the storage account at the end using below code.

```
# Unmount a mount point
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/{storage-account}/{container-name}")
```

Hope this will save your day.